# Woocommerce: is it possible to replace "download" a file with simply read the file on screen?

Tags: plugins

woocommerce is the perfect tool for what I want to do, except that I want clients to access a html5 page they paid for (not downloading it).
Apparently woocommerce doesn't do this...
Do you know a complementary plugin that could do that, or can you give me advices to modify this in woocommerce files?
Tx in advance!
BI

Comment: Theme and plugin recommendations are off topic [per the help screen](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Under Woocommerce > Settings, there's an option to set the file download method.

[image]