# Make downloadable ebook read online without download option

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

My site has downloadable ebooks only (all pdf, sometimes epub together). Now I want to disable/hide the download button after purchase; instead, a 'read' button to let customers read online, preferably get the pdf link and push it to a flipbook or an online reader (external/internal). I have searched for days but couldn't get any good solution on how to do that! I need a solution in woocommerce (not EDD or others) since our mobile app is synched with this.

I would really appreciate it if anybody could give me a direction! If there's a plugin, custom solution, or which online reader of flipbook solution is good for this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this has already been answered as to what you are after?

Please [follow this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105663/124452) and read the provided answer.

Hopefully that helps!